# YUI Editor - Image Upload

Tags: image, upload, editor, file-upload, yui

Is there a plugin to upload images via the Images window, that will work with YUI 2.8.0r4 ?
There is one but that only works with 2.3.1 :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/ - isn't this the one you need?

Comment: Does this allow uploading via the editor images panel then? :S

Comment: If you will connect it I think ;)

Answer (score 2):

see this link,

http://allmybrain.com/2009/07/01/example-image-upload-with-yui-rich-text-editor-270/

It is done for YUI 2.7.0 it also works with 2.8.0r4. I'm using it.